# How to export filename with custom format?

Tags: excel, vba

This is code

```
    Private Sub SaveFile(ByVal Category_Name As Variant)
Dim dif
dif = "_DeviceInfo"

Dim wbTarget As Workbook
Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Add
With wsSource
    With .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))
        .AutoFilter .Range("M1").Column, Category_Name
   .Copy

       
       wbTarget.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    True, Transpose:=True
       
        wbTarget.Worksheets(1).Name = Category_Name & dif
        wbTarget.SaveAs Target_Folder & Category_Name & dif & ".csv", 62
        wbTarget.Close False
        
    End With
    
End With

Set wbTarget = Nothing
End Sub
```

Output now `1_DeviceInfo.csv`

And I want to change to this format `0000X_DeviceInfo.csv` [x= count in M Column][1]

if count = 11 `000XX_DeviceInfo.csv`
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NA7QG.png

Comment: You can use `Format$`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want change your number (as string) from format "1" to "00001" which length is 5 then you can do something like this:

```
n=string(5-len(n), "0")&n
```

Comment: `Format$(n,"00000")`.